# On AIX 6100-05-02-1034 how can I create custom umask for a specific directory?

Tags: aix, umask

On AIX 6100-05-02-1034 how can I create custom umask for a specific directory?

Comment: What you ask is not available through traditional umask, for what I know. I have no knowledge of AIX, but I suppose it provides ACL (access control list) with which you probably can play to achieve your aim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Umaks on all UNIX based systems that I know of are process specific, not directory specific. You will need to make some fancy hacks to your environment to automaticaly set the umask for the process when changing to your specific directory or play with ACLs for more control.